# SSL Tomcat Configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, config

I am using tomcat 5.5 and configured keystore and added this connector inside server.xml file

```
<Connector port="443" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
       enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
       acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true";
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But I am not sure why when I type in `https://locahost` the browser tells me "This program cannot display the webpage".

Comment: what about the location of the keystore if it is not in the default location.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Tomcat's logs?

- Perhaps the connector could not start up.
- Perhaps Tomcat could not read or find the .keystore you configured.
- Perhaps the .keystore has a password which Tomcat does not know about.
- Perhaps another process is already bound to that port.

The logs will probably tell you exactly which of these is going on.

Comment: but my tomcat logs folder is empty? is it inside apache-tomcat-5.5 ->logs ? when i run http://localhost:8080 it return me Cannot display also but in IBM i run my project that works fine http://localhost:8080/ProjectPage.faces

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have your browser configured to use a web proxy. In this case, make sure that localhost and 127.0.0.1 are exceptions to using this proxy under the browser's preferences or options. ALSO make sure that localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in your `/etc/hosts` file. Which in windows is under `\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: I checked my hosts file ya it is mapped. You mean the option or preferences is it internet option ? because i cannot get any option or preferences from the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the port 
localhost **:443**